# Closed subsets in Coxeter groups

Tags: coxeter-groups

Let $W$ be a finite or infinite Coxeter group and $\Phi^+$ the set of its positive roots.

In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5557), a subset $A$ of $\Phi^+$ is closed if for all $a, b \in A$, $r_1 a + r_2 b \in \Phi^+$ for some $r_1, r_2 \ge 0$ implies that $r_1 a + r_2 b \in A$. A subset is biclosed if it is closed and its complement is also closed.

Are the  following resuls correct? Are there some references about these?

The union of two disjoint biclosed subsets of $\Phi^+$ is biclosed.

Any help would be greated appreciated！

Comment: How do you define roots of a Coxeter group (associated to a Coxeter system)? the Coxeter group is the same for $B_n$ and $C_n$, $n\ge 3$, while the root system are not the same. Isn't the question natural to ask simply starting with a root system?

Comment: @YCor: The question does seem more natural when posed for 'root systems' if defined in a suitable way; but Deodhar's notion of such a root system for an arbitrary Coxeter group is even more reasonable here: for example, in the finite BC situation, the use of unit vectors as roots solves the problem here.    (See Deodhar's paper or my 1990 book on reflection groups for more details.)      On the other hand, I'm not convinced that this question is really at research-level.

Answer (score 3):

The union of two disjoint biclosed sets is not biclosed in general. For a counterexample consider the root system of type $A_2$. We denote the simple roots by $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

We claim that the set $\{\alpha\}\subseteq \Phi^+$ is biclosed. It is closed since the only scalar multiple of $\alpha$ that belongs to $\Phi^+$ is $\alpha$ itself. The complement $\Phi^+\backslash\{a\}=\{\alpha+\beta,\beta\}$ is closed since
\begin{align*}
\left\lbrace\,r_1(\alpha+\beta)+r_2\beta\mid r_1,r_2\geq 0\,\right\rbrace\cap\Phi^{+}=\{\alpha+\beta,\beta\}.
\end{align*}

Similarly, $\{\beta\}\subseteq\Phi^+$ is closed. On the other hand, the union $A=\{\alpha\}\cup\{\beta\}=\{\alpha,\beta\}$ is not biclosed. It is not closed because $\alpha+\beta\in\Phi^+\backslash A$.